# How much server power does Worldpress take?

Tags: performance, server

I have multiple Wordpress websites on my server(And a game server and Tomcat) and I'm a little paranoid about my servers health. How much does a newly installed Wordpress take typically?

Comment: This is impossible to answer because it depends what you are doing with it.

Comment: @Wyck I said CLEAN Wordpress if you didn't read the question

Comment: Clean is not a clear definition, what exactly does that mean?  Which theme, no plugins, no traffic, which type of server, etc? Also you accepted a horrible answer which is wrong.

Comment: How much world would a WordPress take if a WordPress could take world?

Comment: No traffic = WordPress doesn't run at all = no 'power' used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of question is open ended to answer because it depends on many variables. The typical memory usage of bare WP usually starts at 15MB and scales up.

What you can do is turn on debugging and install the [Debug Bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) plugin and it will show you the amount of memory you're using.

In `wp-config.php` set `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

[image: Debug Bar plugin showing memory usage]

Another plugin which shows peak memory usage: [TPC Memory Usage](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tpc-memory-usage/)

Comment: A new WP install does not need 15MB allocated for it.

Comment: I never said it did, I said a "typical" install starts at 15MB, you would be hard pressed to run below 10MB without any caching in place even on a bare install.

Comment: A new install runs at 4MB of memory on my server.  Also good link to a plugin not updated since 2.9....  Anyway on what server is 4-15MB going to affect?  He asked a simple question and you gave him a complex answer.  You do have a picture in your answer that really shows nothing.  You didn't mention how to set up indexes right or actually do a clean install and see what the variance is.  Anyway I have large WP sites with 1000+ posts/pages and 50K users and they run under 15MB...  It is all about the number of queries hitting your DB and if you allow crappy plugins.

Comment: The plugin update date has nothing to do with anything, it works perfectly fine, your attitude is immature and not going to go very far on this site.

Comment: But everything I said is true.  Either you give a simple answer like mine or give a complex right answer.  You did not have either sorry.  I can help you run WP under 15MB if you want.

Comment: @SumTingWong you need to sort your attitude out. Stop trolling and start learning how to be courteous.